# How to remove an empty Mongo database with the same name as a populated database?

Tags: mongodb

I accidentally created two databases with the same name. When I do `show dbs` in my Mongo shell, I get this:

```
> show dbs
admin (empty)
local 0.078GB
example_development (empty)
example_development 0.078GB
```

Is there a way to remove the empty db without tampering with the populated one?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible.  Can you edit your question to include the output from `db.adminCommand('listDatabases')`?

Answer (score 1):

The database names aren't the same, its just that one has a non-printable character in it which mongo shell's javascript interface is suppressing for you.

In mongo its up to the driver to make sure the user is not able to submit non-standard data to the server but [it has been demonstrated](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongosf-2012/mongodb-security-considerations) that BSON is remarkably flexible in what it can store.

Since you're talking about an entire database the easiest way to fix this problem would be to shutdown mongo and remove the database files. You can find where those files are with the `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` command.

Answer (score 0):

[Wes Widner answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25696790/1481489) in that you most likely have a non-printable character. However, rather than remove the files from the filesystem directly, I prefer a more programmatic approach. They key here is to never really call the database by its literal name, but instead keep a reference to the name in variable form:

1. List all databases
2. Filter those databases to match the criteria you're seeking
3. Transform the resulting list (array) into just the database names
4. Select the specific index of the db in question (I couldn't figure out a way to iterate through each resulting database and apply `getSiblingDB` to each of them).
5. Pass that into [`db.getSiblingDB`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) and issue a `db.dropDatabase`

## Working Example

```
use bogus;
db.createCollection('blah');
db.getCollectionNames(); // [ "blah", "system.indexes" ]

use admin;
db.adminCommand({listDatabases:1}).databases.filter(function(d){
    return d.name === 'bogus';
}).map(function(d){
    return d.name;
}); // [ "bogus" ]


// use [0] here since we now 'bogus' was at index 0 in previous
// getSiblingDB will allow us to issue dropDatabase on the string
// representation of the database
db.getSiblingDB(db.adminCommand({listDatabases:1}).databases.filter(function(d){
    return d.name === 'bogus';
}).map(function(d){
    return d.name;
})[0]).dropDatabase();
```

## Tailoring It to Your Problem

Instead of specifically filtering by `name`, we want to filter by `sizeOnDisk`. Be sure not to select "admin" here, so run the `adminCommand` with the filter/map first to get the applicable index. Chances are "admin" will be at index 0, so your database in question will most likely be at index 1:

```
db.getSiblingDB(db.adminCommand({listDatabases:1}).databases.filter(function(d){
    return !d.sizeOnDisk;
}).map(function(d){
    return d.name;
})[1]).dropDatabase(); // note usage of [1] here
```